# Mercurial: block commits if subrepos are dirty?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-subrepos

Is there any simple way to prevent commits to a repository if it has dirty subrepos?

It's really annoying when a subrepo is accidentally committed along with a parent repository.

Comment: I have wanted this as well, and discussed it some time ago on the Mercurial mailing list (and hacked up some patches to do it), but I know of no supported way at present.  If someone has one, I would love to see it as well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where your line for *simple* lands but you could do a hook like this:

```
for subrepo in $(find $(hg root) -type d -name .hg) ; do
  if [ "$(hg --repository ${subrepo$$.hg} status -mard)" != "" ] ; then
    echo Uncommitted subrepo changes in ${subrepo%%.hg}
    exit 1
  fi
done
```

Save that in something like `~/bin/dirtysubrepos` and then add this to your `~/.hgrc`:

```
[hooks]
precommit.dirtysuprepos = ~/bin/dirtysubrepos
```

**Disclaimer:** This code has never been typed anywhere except this textbox, so it almost certainly has syntax bugs.

Comment: Hrm, I was hoping it wouldn't come to that… I guess it's better than nothing, though.

Comment: sure, but on the upside look at my beautiful shell :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on Ry4an's answer for some reason (no "Add comment" link for me to click on), but there's a minor typo in his answer: there's an `${subrepo$$.hg}` that should be `${subrepo%%.hg}`.